# mysqli_fetch_assoc error when trying to select WooCommerce values from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently making a WordPress plugin and trying to select a few values from WooCommerce database and all I keep getting is the same error. What might be wrong?

My Code:

```
function prntPage()
{
    //Connect is defined somewhere else
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
     while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["order_item_id"]. " - Product Name: " . $row["order_item_name"]. " - Order_ID" . $row["order_id"]. "<br>";
    }       
}
```

The Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ExamenProject\wp-content\plugins\drukkebaasjes-sizedata\drukkebaasjes-sizedata.php:54 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ExamenProject\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286): prntPage('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ExamenProject\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ExamenProject\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ExamenProject\wp-admin\admin.php(224): do_action('toplevel_page_p...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ExamenProject\wp-content\plugins\drukkebaasjes-sizedata\drukkebaasjes-sizedata.php on line 54

Comment: `$result->fetch_assoc()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`. Every time you get an error like `undefined method` or `undefined function` you should check the [manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Instead of using `mysqli` directly, you should look into using Wordpress db-class instead. You can read about it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 2):

With Wordpress there is the [WPDB class and methods](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for that purpose. Try the following instead:

```
function prntPage() {
    global $wpdb;

    // The SQL query
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items");

    // Loop though rows data
    foreach( $results as $row ){
        echo "id: " . $row->order_item_id . " - Product Name: " . $row->order_item_name . " - Order_ID" . $row->order_id . "<br>";
    }
}
```

This function code works without error now.